# how to call overloaded method in java?

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I am having trouble trying to call the methods "displayInformation" in main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class overload
{
        public static void main (String[ ] args )
        {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         int task;
            System.out.println("Select task 1-3: ");
            task=keyboard.nextInt();
            if (task==1)
            {
            OverloadedMethod o= new OverloadedMethod();
            System.out.println( o.displayInformation(int,int) );
            }
            else if (task==2)
            {
            OverloadedMethod oo= new OverloadedMethod();
            System.out.println( oo.displayInformation(String, int ) ); 
            }
            else if (task==3)
            {
            OverloadedMethod ooo= new OverloadedMethod();
            System.out.println( ooo.displayinformation(String,String) );     
            }

        }
}


class OverloadedMethod
{

     public void displayInformation (int num1, int num2)
     {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Please enter your first int value: ");
           num1=keyboard.nextInt();
              System.out.print("Please enter your second int value: ");
              num2=keyboard.nextInt();

              System.out.print("Values entered: " + num1 + " and " + num2);

     }

     public void displayInformation (String str, int num)
     {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Please enter your first string value: ");
           str=keyboard.nextLine();
              System.out.print("Please enter your second int value: ");
              num=keyboard.nextInt();

              System.out.print("Values entered: " + str + " and " + num);
     }

      public void displayInformation(String str1, String str2)
      {
                Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.print("Please enter your first string value: ");
           str1=keyboard.nextLine();
              System.out.print("Please enter your second string value: ");
              str2=keyboard.nextLine();

              System.out.print("Values entered: " + str1 + " and " + str2);
      }
}
```

In the program. I ask the user to choose a task, and each task calls a different "displayInformation" method to ask for either an int&int or int&string or string&string. I am having trouble calling the methods in main though, I keep getting the error "error: '.class' expected" for the lines where I create the object..I get errors only for varibales o and oo but not ooo. Why is this?

Comment: I think you mean `new OverloadedMethod();`

Comment: C'mon create an instance as x like `OverloadedMethod x =newOverloadedMethod()` then call the method with `x` instance like `x.displayInformation(19,90)`

Comment: You are providing 3 like-named methods with unused parameters and then forcing them to be used merely to distinguish the methods.  Surely you can find a cleaner way.   But if you want to force the compiler to figure out which overload to call, you have to pass actual elements of the correct types, as in `o.displayInformation ( 0, 0 )` to get the int, int one.

Comment: @javalava you are passing exact `String`, it doesn't make sense buddy, you need to send a real string (no its class), like `ooo.displayinformation("Hello","Buddy")`, and also these methods are void, how you really want to print them?!!

Answer (score 0):

`OverloadedMethod` is a class and don't have constructor with parameters defined.

So you have to do

```
   OverloadedMethod o= new OverloadedMethod();


   switch (task){
   case 1:
    System.out.println( o.displayInformation(num1,num2) );break;
   case 2:
    System.out.println( o.displayInformation(str,num ) );break; 
   case 3:
    System.out.println( o.displayinformation(str1,str2) );break;
   default:
      System.out.println("invalid option");
```

And you need to define and assign values to `num1` `num2` `str` `num` `str` and `str2`

And not less important, `displayInfomartion` must return `Object` (or subclasses) that have `toString()` implemented to be readable for humans.

Example :

`public String displayInformation(...)`

Comment: I defined them and asked the user to enter values for num1 num2 str num str and str2 in the displayInformation methods. Do the have to be defined in main?